# Gzipped tar file is bigger than its content

Tags: bash, tar, filesize

I have in my bash script `tar` command to create daily files backup. The code is:

```
tar czfP /path/to/file.tar.gz /path/to/source
```

It works, but `tar.gz` file has size of 14GB and when I untar that, the sum size of all files is about only 9GB.

I've found that I should be caused by white space blocks and as a solution I've read I should use the `i` argument, but the final filesize is the same when I use it (approx. 14GB).

```
tar czfPi /path/to/file.tar.gz /path/to/source
```

Where is the problem, it's really in using (in my code bad using) of `i` argument, or I'd need to upgrade my code any way?

Thanks
Roman

Comment: Does your source contain thousands of small files, and not really any compressible files?

Comment: can you show the output of `gzip -l file.tar.gz`  (that's lower-case L, not 1)

Comment: If your data is already compressed, (or is otherwise uncompressible), then yes, the result will be larger than the original.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin still, 9GB to 14GB for `tar` (assuming 0% compression) is an awfully high ratio of metadata to actual files... it probably wastes even more space in the filesystem!

Comment: You misunderstood `-i`, don't use it at any time

Comment: Run `find /path/to/source -print0 |xargs -0 file -b |sort -u` and share the results, please.

Comment: @M.M: there are both, small and big file (but not so big, the biggest are images/pdfs with size of tens MB max.). Than there is a lot on small (in KBs/up to 2MBs) files. The result of `gzip -l file.tar.gz` is `compressed | uncompressed | ratio ------ 10.4GB | 3.2GB | -99.9%` (it's another file, so the size is different than in question... hm, the ratio  is bigger for this file, 14/9 vs. 10/3...). About `i`, OK, I've remove from script, I thought it could be what I'm looking for :-/

Comment: That output makes no sense, maybe your gzip  is failing to handle large files? Ratio cannot be negative, and it is impossible that 3.2G tar would zip to 10.4G tar.gz

Comment: at any rate, you could experiment with making the tarball first (don't use `-z` option, call the file `.tar`) and then use `gzip` on the tar file

Comment: @M.M: I really don't know. In tar.gz file is all what should be there (I checked it out). The size of 9GB in question or 3.2GB in comment above is real size of uncompressed files. And 14/10.4GB is size I see in console in my system (mac os x), in file properties and in filezilla on server.

Comment: @M.M: so you mean to try `tar cfP /...file.tar.gz /path/to/source`? I'm newbie in this, so I rather ask before trying :-)

Comment: @Roman take out `.gz`  . "tar" is a program that concatenates lots of files into one, "gz" is a program that turns one big file into one small file.  you can do the two steps separately,  the `-z` switch to tar means to use a pipe to do both steps without writing the big file to disk

Comment: @M.M: yeah, I see that. `tar cfP /...file.tar /path/to/source` is what you meant

Comment: Hm, `tar` file has size cca. 12GB... I try to download this file from server, and find st. out using -l (+ read about that)... So, gz has 10.4GB, tar has 12GB (it means that gz really compress tar file) and I'm going to see what size has `tar` content :-) Tomorrow I'll come back and write here news... For today thx for your advices.

Comment: @M.M: Ok, I have any other info for you. I created `tar` file on server, using `tar cfP file.tar /data/to/tar`. `tar` file had 11.88GB. Then, locally in Mac's Terminal, I've created `tar.gz` file from that, using `tar -cvzf file.tar.gz file.tar`. Size 7.66GB. `gzip -l file.tar.gz` returns me the same as before, `-99.9% ratio etc.` (and about 4GB uncompressed size). When I unzip this gz file, `gunzip file.tar.gz`, it had back 11.88GB. OK. Then I untared it, `tar -xvf file.tar`. Final size of all unziped files is cca 4GB (the same size as I had before when I made tar.gz on server directly).

Comment: sounds like `gzip -l` has a bug... and maybe you really do just have millions of tiny files.  (If you're not sure exactly what files you have, investigate that perhaps by making smaller tars of subdirectories until you find where the problem is

Comment: @M.M: hm... the total size of unziped files is 4GB, the number of files can be... approximately 60,000. Dirs in total about 1,000. Are these amounts reason of so big tar&tar.gz files? What do you mean? I can do a research in smaller dirs as you told, but have not so many time for that, maybe on evenings after work, it seems there is no better way than test it on smaller parts (I hoped I have just any small error in my script which I don't understand).